# Rails ActiveRecord: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently updated rails application from `4.0` to `4.1`. When I try to execute  `Department.where("conditions").all(:include => [:users])` this give the following error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Any help on how to fix this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: `Department.where("conditions").include(:users).all`  the `all` method should not have any arguments (you passed a hash)

Comment: @LesNightingill `includes` with s in the end, and it will work without `all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strange because `all` in 4.0 [has not arguments](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L24)

But 3.2 [has](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L158)

Probably the problem occurred during the upgrade from 3.2 to 4.0, not from 4.0 to 4.1

You need to replace your query using [`includes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) to

```
Department.includes(:users).where("conditions")
```

And you don't need `all`